# cordova geolocation plugin doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

Device: **Android**

Target Version: **25**

Cordova version: **7.0.1**

I'm using cordova-plugin-geolocation https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation but with some devices doesn't work. I tried the application 
with these devices:

1. Huawei P9 Lite VNS-L31 Android 7.0 ---> work
2. Huawei P9 Lite VNS-L21 Android 7.0---> work only if i disallow the battery optimization of the application.
3. Huawei P9 Android 7.0--> doesn't work
4. One Plus 3 Android 7.1.1 --> work
5. Samsung S8 Android 7.0 --> work

CODE:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessPoint, onErrorPoint,{ timeout:10000 });
 var onSuccessPoint = function (position) {
///SUCCESS CODE
}
function onErrorPoint(error) {
//ERROR CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You app must run in background mode , if your app not white listed under battery optimization your app won't run. use this cordova plugin to white list your app from battery  optimization,

Install

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/thomas550i/cordova-plugin-doze-Optimize
```

Javascript code

```
cordova.plugins.DozeOptimize.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(function (responce){
  console.log("IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations: "+responce);
      if(responce=="false")
      {
        cordova.plugins.DozeOptimize.RequestOptimizations(function (responce){
          console.log(responce);
        }, function (error){
        console.error("BatteryOptimizations Request Error"+error);          
        });
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Application already Ignoring Battery Optimizations");
      }     
}, function (error){
console.error("IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations Error"+error);    
});
```

Comment: the above mentioned plugin doesn't work correctly, due to the following issue - https://github.com/thomas550i/cordova-plugin-doze-Optimize/issues/3. Long story short - when the plugin ask a user to turn off doze mode, it should WAIT until user returns their answer, then to proceed according to it.